# Jenkins Maven build test failure

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am getting below error while building a maven project, here is what I've done.

Installed manually in to the docker container:

```
root@926ba6d236aa:/# whereis mvn
mvn: /usr/bin/mvn /usr/share/man/man1/mvn.1.gz

root@926ba6d236aa:/# mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
```

Configured in `Jenkins`-> Global Tool Configuration

```
Name :- M2_HOME
MAVEN_HOME :- /usr/share/maven
```

I've also tried `install automatically` on Jenkins.

While building I'm getting this error:

> ```
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test
> ```
>
> (default-test) on project Server: There are test failures. [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] Please refer to
>   /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Server/target/surefire-reports for the
>   individual test results. [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any
>   exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and
>   [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream. . . . .
>       **Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE**

Comment: It seems like a test case is failing. Can you check in the Jenkins GUI if this is the case?

Comment: I skipped the test case using following command "clean install -DskipTests" and able to take build successfully, 

But i will like to use test case without error. Is there other way to rectify that issue.